Elastic APM Agent - Laravel Queue
I have installed self hosted elastic apm solution for my laravel app with kibana for visualization of traces and apm elastic agent for auto instrumentation. My laravel app uses queues but the apm elastic agent is not displaying those queues in Kibana. I have tried it on multiple laravel apps with different laravel and php versions but same problem. I would be really grateful for suggestions in this regard.
Thanks
